# Replace cell content in Excel with array content

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet which includes a text column which stores both text and numbers. I am trying to extract serial numbers, which are 13 digits long, and replace the column content with these serial numbers. I was able to extract the serial numbers but I am stalling on how to replace the cell.value with the serial numbers. Below is my initial approach:

```
Sub extract_digits()
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant, arrElem As Variant
Dim final_arr As Variant
With Worksheets("Test_1")
    For Each cell In .Range("H5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
        arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ") 
        For Each arrElem In arr
            If Len(arrElem) = 13 Then MsgBox arrElem
            
        Next arrElem
    
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of displaying a message box, you can use `cell.value=arrElem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option (Remove Letters From Strings/Numbers/Cells With User Defined Function) from this site should do the trick:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3244-excel-remove-letters-from-strings-cells-numbers.html

**Function below is from above website, it's not mine**

```
Function StripChar(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Global = True
.Pattern = "\D"
StripChar = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

**How is this working**

Is using Regular Expressions (RegEx). The .Pattern means it's looking for any non numeric (ie 0 to 9), it's then using the .Replace function to replace any non numeric with nothing.

**How do you use this**

**Option 1** You can either use it directly in a column next to your column, eg =StripChar(H5) and then just copy that formula down.

**Option 2** Alternatively using your code

```
Sub extract_digits()
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant, arrElem As Variant
Dim final_arr As Variant
With Worksheets("Test_1")
    For Each cell In .Range("H5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
        cell = StripChar(cell.Value)
    
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I would need to change the pattern in the function StripChar as my cell contains all kind of text to include other numbers; I would only need 13 digits numbers. @ACCtionMan

Comment: A negative lookahead completed the function to meet my needs. `Function StripChar(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Global = True
.Pattern = "(?!\b\d{13}\b)(\b\w+\b)"
StripChar = .Replace(Txt, "+")
End With
End Function `